# domain + port regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to create regex for Java app for find every `xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xx:XXXXX` with no limit of sub-domains length. In code:

```
msgEditOne = msgText.replaceAll("REGEXCODE", "replaced");
```

Comment: you means the length of "xxxxxx" is not limited?

Comment: Any reason for not using String.split(":")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one should do the job...

`([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:[0-9]+`